# Does GPL cover single page web apps fully

Tags: gpl, agpl-3.0, website

If you're trying to make sure future changes to a single page app (including perhaps adding a backend API) are GPL'd, is it sufficient to release the code under the GPL, or is the AGPL required?

Comment: GPL says anyone who gives you a copy of the app must give you the source. AGPL says anyone who runs it on a network server for you must also give you the source. Will people be distributing copies or just running servers?

Comment: The app as it stands is purely front-end.

Comment: So will people be distributing copies or just running servers?

Comment: If someone serves the web page they'll be distributing a copy. If someone runs it through a precompiler, they'd also need to make any modifications to the source available, I would think.